# Trying to figure out my web collector isn't working

Tags: python, web-crawler

I'm new to coding (python) for this project.

Just trying to make a web crawling bot for ebay.
I got the original code for other web store on online, while it needed to be edited a lot, I made the original version working on other web store! It was a triumph. But ebay's structure is diffrent, I needed to edit for ebay.ca. (It must be a simple job!) I reviewed and edited whole day and finally didn't find out lol.

This is the code for ebay crawling.

#If I need to explanation in this line, it will search one by one search_string and save information (date, name, price, shipping price) on csv.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse
import datetime
import requests
import utils
import time
import random
import re

# result file goes
out_path = 'EBout/'

global_url_path = 'http://www.ebay.ca/'

# timeout
request_get_timeout = 5 # sec

# search
search_string = [
    'ipad10'
    'ipad11'
]

def get_price(html, current_filtter):        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    #with open(out_path + '_' +'full_content.html',  "w", encoding='utf-8') as fp_full_content:
        #fp_full_content.write(str(soup))

    item_count = 0  # Counter to keep track of imported items

    for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'}):

        # title
        item_name = item.find(class_="s-item__title").find('span').get_text(strip=True)
        # price
        item_price = item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'}).get_text(strip=True)
        # shipping price
        item_shipping = item.find(class_='s-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost').get_text(strip=True)
         
        # title collect
        title = item_name[0]

        # price collect 
        price_text = item_price[0]
        temp_price = re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', price_text)
        
        if not temp_price.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
            continue
        price = float(temp_price)

        item_shipping_text = item_shipping[0]
        temp_shipping_price = re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', item_shipping_text)
        if not temp_shipping_price.replace('.', '', 1).isdigit():
            continue
        shipping = float(temp_shipping_price)

        # date today
        now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


        # csv format
        info  = '{0},"{1}",{2},{3}\n'.format(now, title, price, shipping)
        
        # save into csv 
        with open(out_path + 'EBprice.csv',  "a", encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            fp.write(info)
            print(info)
        
        item_count += 1  # Increment the item counter
        if item_count >= 3:  # Stop importing after x items
            break        

        
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    if not utils.check_out_folder():
        exit(-1)
    headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-CA,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    for item in search_string:
        try:
            url = global_url_path + 'sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=' + parse.quote(item) + '&_sacat=0&_sop=15'
            print('collecting' + item)
            result = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=request_get_timeout)
            html = result.content

            get_price(html, item)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            random_wait_time = random.uniform(10, 22)
            time.sleep(random_wait_time)
```

this is utils.py

```
import errno
import os
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse


def check_folder(folder):
    try:
        if not(os.path.isdir(folder)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder))
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            print(folder + ' failed to create the folder.')
            raise
        return False
    return True

def check_out_folder():    
    return check_folder('EBout')
```

When I start this, it will generate only "I'm searching for this item" and "0"
No csv was created on EBout, but _full_content.html.

I thought I could do it with ChatGPT since I could edit some scripts I needed without ChatGPT, but to me, this project is much more complex than I did before.

If it would be helpful to you to the original script, I will upload it too.
Can I get help to make this crawler work?
Thanks for reading!

*What I tried to do: It will search multiple items one by one in search_string and save the cheapest (price + shipping) item's information (date, name, price, shipping price) on csv for ebay.

**Since I'm new here, I don't know but I have some experience with communities that hate deleting posts, in case you are worried about deleting the information, this thread will not be deleted by myself.

Comment: It’s great that you’re learning coding—keep at it! But this is probably too big of a project for a first foray into coding with Python if I read your question right. Also SO is for specific technical questions not general “help me fix my program” questions.

Comment: Also I would strongly recommend reading a website’s terms of service before writing a program to scrape it. I don’t know in this case but it wouldn’t surprise me at all if this didn’t violate eBay’s TOS. I may be wrong but if you haven’t checked I would.

Comment: Thanks for comment! is it working correctly? Anyway, I will check it out. I was trying to do easier study today, I guess it's pretty big like you said. But I wanna finish this later on, someday!

Comment: BraveGingercookie to be honest I have no idea. But you’ll have a much easier time learning with small simple programs that build on each other starting with simple concepts like I/O and building up to more advanced concepts like closures. Little by little works better than all at once. It ensures you are learning a concept in isolation so you can really experiment and get a feel for it, and it makes troubleshooting so much easier than in a case like this one. Troubleshooting is hard for an experienced dev let alone for someone who is new.

Comment: Just curious, is building a solid structure easier than troubleshooting in your experience?

Comment: What do you mean by building a solid structure?

Comment: Before you program, you are building a system in your mind, or at least paper. I meant that system. Structure.

Comment: And the solid structure means.. like.. a structure you are "strongly" hoping no errors. I am like a person building a moderate structure that hoping no errors. Do you feel it?

Comment: Designing up front (iteratively) is more important for large programs than for the small ones a beginner should write to learn to code. But troubleshooting is always going to be there—it’s a core part of programming.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm trying to understand my coworker. And I feel with this project, troubleshooting is kinda agony.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the parsing variables. You are erroring on the `item_shipping =` line and it's breaking out of `get_price`

Here is a slightly modified version to have it stay in `get_price`:

```
    # title
    item_name = item.find(class_="s-item__title").find('span').get_text(strip=True)
    # price
    item_price = item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'}).get_text(strip=True)
    # shipping price
    try:
        item_shipping = item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost'}).get_text(strip=True)
    except:
        item_shipping = '0.0'
     
    # title collect
    title = item_name[0]

    # price collect 
    price_text = item_price[1:]
    temp_price = re.sub(r'[^0-9.]', '', price_text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's slightly need to more work to go but you found that missing parts! Now they're collecting date/S/20.0 0.0. (The problem is repeating that again and again lol but maybe later)